# timeticks en python

Tags: python, datetime

Con este código paso timeticks a python, el problema es que me salen solo dias, horas, segundos,

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import datetime
ticks = 197740964
seconds = ticks/100
datetime.timedelta(seconds=seconds)
print (datetime.timedelta(seconds=seconds))
```

salida

22 days, 21:16:49.640000

Como puedo sacar también años y meses?

Comment: Los meses tienen distinta duración; no tiene sentido hablar de cuantos meses a menos que sepas la fecha/hora de inicio (cuando comienzas a contar los ticks).

Comment: si , los meses se que serían timeticks / lo que sea, 100 * 60 *60 * 24* 30 , el timetick, lo tendre entero, pero necesitaría sacar la fecha con años y meses, de todas formas no se si te he entendido bien

Comment: podrías ponerme un ejemplo de lo de fecha/Hora de inicio?

Comment: ¿Lo que pretendes es averiguar cuantos años, meses, dias, horas, minutos y segundos han trascurrido desde 'ticks', o averiguar la fecha que corresponde a ese 'ticks'?

Answer (score 0):

Dado que en tu pregunta, la variable `'ticks/100'` es un intervalo de tiempo transcurrido en segundos, y asumiendo que lo que quieres es saber cuanto tiempo ha pasado hasta el momento actual, en otras unidades de tiempo, la opción más fácil parece ser usar la biblioteca `'dateutil'`, que proporciona una extensión a `'datetime'`para hacer más fácil los cálculos con fechas.
Como siempre, recomiendo visitar la [documentación](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples.html#relativedelta-examples) para comprender su uso y posibilidades.

En este caso, la instrucción `'relativedelta(inicio,final)'` sería lo adecuado, pues nos da el tiempo total transcurrido, y opciones para acceder a cada uno de los valores de tiempo de forma individual.

Te pongo el código de ejemplo, que se comenta solo.

```
from datetime import *
from dateutil.relativedelta import *

ticks   = 197740964

final   = datetime.now()
inicio  = timedelta(seconds=(ticks//100))+final
total   = relativedelta(inicio,final)

y = (relativedelta(inicio,final).years)
M = (relativedelta(inicio,final).months)
d = (relativedelta(inicio,final).days)
h = (relativedelta(inicio,final).hours)
m = (relativedelta(inicio,final).minutes)
s = (relativedelta(inicio,final).seconds)

print('Desde', inicio, 'hasta', final)
print(total)
print('años:',y)
print('meses:',M)
#etc...
```

Y la salida sería esta:

```
Desde 2021-10-29 18:23:04.825205 hasta 2021-10-06 21:06:15.825205
relativedelta(days=+22, hours=+21, minutes=+16, seconds=+49)
años: 0
meses: 0
```